# CentOS 100% full disk, but no there any large file

Tags: storage, centos6, disk-space-utilization

In my CentOS server, hard disk is full but no there any large file in hard disk.
I check files size with `du` command
When i reboot the server problem is solve but after 1 or 2 days this problem happens again!
How can i solve this problem for always?

Note: i using CentOS 6.5 with SSD hard drive

Comment: Look over on the right under related - there is plenty of information there.

Comment: @lain i see all related topics! but many of problems in these topics about log files and large files! but i haven't any large file in my server!

Comment: Many of those Q&A will have techniques in them that will aid you in gathering information to diagnose your problem. Right now your question is unanswerable because it basically reads like this. `My disks get full, reboot fix. HALP !` http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6074/do-you-have-a-checklist-that-can-help-me-ask-a-better-question

Answer (score 2):

When you see disk space being consumed but the files consuming it are not visible in the file system, it usually means the files are being kept open by a running process.

The space will be freed once the process is terminated. Rebooting is one way of terminating processes, which is why the space is freed on reboot.

You can use `lsof` to look for processes that are using deleted files and terminate individual processes instead of rebooting.